# How to reduce number of decimal Mathematica outputs in excel

Tags: export

I have a code which returns numbers with 20 decimals, when I copy them and paste in excel I can't reduce number of decimals, Is there any special way or trick to copy and paste so that I can reduce number of decimals?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can use this approach.

```
datum = N[Pi, 20]
```

> `3.1415926535897932385`

```
excelNum = Round[datum, 10^-8] // N;
excelNum // FullForm
```

> `` 3.14159265` ``

Comment: Many thanks, however I knew how to reduce number of decimals using Mathematica code but I wanted to do so without it.

Comment: @Wisdom. I am not a Mathematica guru, so somebody might post an answer proving me wrong, but I don't think it can be done without running some code on the selected data. You could make pallete with a button that runs a script to apply the code to selected data to make the digit reduction more convenient.

Comment: @Wisdom - If you want to automatically `Round` all real numbers in output use `$Post = # /. x_Real :> Round[x, 10.^-8] &`  Then use `$Post=.` to return to normal. But then, why not do this in Excel? You can automate with a VBA macro.